# Static variable and template specialization ambiguity

Tags: c++

The [FQA](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/web-vs-c++.html#misfeature-3) poses this code example:

```
#include <cstdio>
template<int n> struct confusing
{
    static int q;
};
template<> struct confusing<1>
{
    template<int n>
    struct q
    {
        q(int x)
        {
            printf("Separated syntax and semantics.\n");
        }
        operator int () { return 0; }
    };
};
char x;
int main()
{
    int x = confusing< SOME_NUMBER_HERE >::q < 3 > (2);
    return 0;
}
```

`q` either refers to `static int q` or `q(int x)` depending on the value of `SOME_NUMBER_HERE`. It seems like a fairly contrived example considering `q` can simply be named something else. `gcc` even has a warning:

```
warning: comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]

     int x = confusing<2>::q < 3 > (2);
```

Is there a practical scenario where this kind of thing is a problem?

Comment: Wow... took a while to see why this even compiles for `SOME_NUMBER_HERE` != 1. I would be surprised if this doesn't turn up as a real problem in a sufficiently large code base, with unsupervised template aficionados at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any but, of course, that does not prove that there are real world examples.

I remember that Andrei Alexandrescu gave a talk about static_if ([slides](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12StaticIfIHadAHammer.pdf)). I think he also addressed template hijacking, which is similar to your example.

Well, if someone can come up with a real example, I'm quite sure that Andrei Alexandrescu is the one. :-)